# DHCP Not Communicating with Wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-server-2008, dhcp

Hi there I have just setup a DHCP server (experiment) on Windows Server 2008; as I have not done this before I have come across a problem. It will issue out Ethernet IP's however when it comes to laptops with wireless they are not being handled by the DHCP server.

I have a wireless router connected to the modem and then everything more or less connected to the router (Wireless and Ethernet) including the server. The router was handling DHCP before I disabled it.

Have I missed something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two IP subnets separated by a (wireless) router.

DHCP servers don't hand out addresses to computers on different IP networks.

Either configure your wireless router as a bridge (i.e. as a plain WAP) or let it provide DHCP service to the separate wireless subnetwork.